# How to fix update user location on func "didUpdateLocations"?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to update location when user access map on my application. I used func `didUpdateLocations` to get the user location but location didn't update, some units when I run on real device. please help me, Thank you.

This is for google map sdk design map on application.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    guard let currentLocation = locations.last else {
        return
    }

    //Update Camera
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: currentLocation.coordinate.longitude, zoom: 18.0)
    mapView.animate(to: camera)

    if mapView.isHidden {
        mapView.isHidden = false
        mapView.camera = camera
    } else {
        mapView.animate(to: camera)
    }
```

Help me to get the exact user location when run project. Thank you.

Comment: Have you set this locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest in viewDidLoad()

Comment: Yes, i have set that, Is it related to my problem?. Do you can explain :D.

Comment: Can you provide more details on your problem? What/how does it "fail"?  What devices are you testing on?  Note that wifi only iPads and iPod touch devices do not have a GPS receiver.

Comment: Paulw11: I used iphone 5 and 6 to check but it fail when position on the device deviates with the real position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please implement start updating user location.Let me know if it still not working

```
locationManager.delegate = self
locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  I have set it up but location update still wrong when i run on real device. I do not understand because i followed example of googleMap SDK IOS before ask the question. Hope experienced people like you can share workarounds.